# counting zeros in columns in data frame in R and express as percentage

Tags: r

I want to count number of zeros in each column in a R data frame and express it as a percentage. This percentage should be added to last row of the original data frame? 
example

```
x <- c(0, 4, 6, 0, 10)
y <- c(3, 0, 9, 12, 15)
z <- c(3, 6, 9, 0, 15)

data_a <- cbind(x,y,z)
```

want to see the zeros in each column and express as percentage

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
x <- c(0, 4, 6, 0, 10)
y <- c(3, 0, 9, 12, 15)
z <- c(3, 6, 9, 0, 15)

data_a <- cbind(x,y,z)
#This is a matrix not a data.frame.    

res <- colSums(data_a==0)/nrow(data_a)*100
```

If you must, `rbind` to the matrix (usually not really a good idea).

```
rbind(data_a, res)
#      x  y  z
#      0  3  3
#      4  0  6
#      6  9  9
#      0 12  0
#     10 15 15
# res 40 20 20
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is one more method using lapply, this would work for a data frame though.

```
lapply(data_a, function(x){ length(which(x==0))/length(x)})
```

Answer (score 2):

A combination of `prop.table` and some `*apply` work can give you the same answer as @Roland's

```
> prop <- apply(data_a, 2, function(x) prop.table(table(x))*100)
> rbind(data_a, sapply(prop, "[", 1))
      x  y  z
[1,]  0  3  3
[2,]  4  0  6
[3,]  6  9  9
[4,]  0 12  0
[5,] 10 15 15
[6,] 40 20 20
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably inelegant, but this is how I went about it when my columns had NAs:

```
#Returns the number of zeroes in a column
numZero <- colSums(vars == 0, na.rm = T)

#Returns the number of non-NA entries in each column
numNA <- colSums(is.na(vars))

#Returns total sample size
numSamp <- rep(nrow(vars), ncol(vars))

#Combine the three
varCheck <- as.data.frame(cbind(numZero, numNA, numSamp))

#Number of observations for that variable
varCheck$numTotal <- varCheck$numSamp - varCheck$numNA

#Percentage zero
varCheck$pctZero <- varCheck$numZero / varCheck$numTotal

#Check which have lower than 1%
varCheck[which(varCheck$pctZero > 0.99),]
```